# Execution time takes 30+ minutes looping through two lists of Dictionaries

Tags: c#, list, sorting, dictionary, compare

Currently my program works like this:

```
List<Dict<string, double>> GroupA;
List<Dict<string, double>> GroupB;
* All dictionaries have the same keys but with dif values

foreach(string key in GroupA[0])
{
      List<double> GroupA_Values;
      foreach(Dict d in GroupA)
          GroupA_Values.add(d[key]);

      List<double> GroupB_Values;
      foreach(Dict d in GroupB)
          GroupB_Values.add(d[key]);

      CompareValuesFunction(GroupA_Values, GroupB_Values);
}
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with "compile time".

Comment: This is not valid C# code.  It'd help if we could see what you're actually doing, as it could very well have an effect on performance.

Comment: What does CompareValuesFunction do? Do you have to copy the values out of the dictionaries before using them?

Comment: You can use `GroupA.Values` and `GroupB.Values` instead of copying the values into a new `List<double>`. Also, to answer your question, you'd need to tell us how many entries are in each dictionary, and then show us the `CompareValuesFunction()` code.

Comment: what is that first foreach doing there? i don't see the point if you're only doing groupA[0] .. ?

Comment: yes. as shown above, i copy the values into lists of doubles before comparing them. CompareValuesFunction loops through the doubles and finds the cutoff points/values where GroupA and GroupB are most seperated (example. 30-100 might include 10 from GroupA and only 2 from GroupB where as 0-400 might include 20 from groupA and 23 from GroupB)

Comment: I dont want all of GroupA and GroupB's values. just the value of the specific key for each dictionary in the group.

Comment: this is being done > 1000 times. and there are ~500 dictionaires

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having a List of dictionaries, you should have a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` where the values is a list of all of the values associated with a particular key.

Currently you're coping every single value in every single dictionary for each dictionary value.  This doesn't scale well at all.  By copying all of the values to lists everything will scale linerly, rather than polynomially.

This setup will also consume less memory (dictionaries consume more memory than other data structures in order to get that fast search speed).

As mentioned in a comment, if we knew more about what `CompareValuesFunction` (i.e. seeing it's code) we may be able to suggest additional improvements.